# redeclaration of 'const Auteur& Oeuvre::auteur'

Tags: c++

I have this error on my code but I can't figure how to correct it. Thank's in advance for the help ! Here is the part of the code where the error is located:

```
const Auteur& auteur getAuteur() { return auteur; }
```

And here is the code:

```
class Auteur {
    private:
    string nom;
    bool prime;
    
    public:
    Auteur(string nom, bool prime = false)
    : nom(nom), prime(prime) {}
    string getNom() { return nom; }
    bool getPrix() { return prime; }
    Auteur(Auteur const&) = delete;
};
class Oeuvre{
    private:
    string titre;
    const Auteur& auteur;
    string langue;
    
    public:
    Oeuvre(string titre, const Auteur& auteur, string langue)
    : titre(titre), auteur(auteur), langue(langue) {}
    string getTitre() { return titre; }
    const Auteur& auteur getAuteur() { return auteur; } // here is the error
```

Comment: You shouldn't name the return type. It should just be `const Auteur& getAuteur() { return auteur; }`.

Comment: There's an extra rogue `auteur` between the return type and the function's name. Once this is fixed and the missing closing brace for the class added, it compiles fine.

Comment: ohhh yea im dumb ty

Comment: You should reconsider the type of `auteur`. Reference type data members cause a lot of problems, it makes value semantics difficult to implement and prevent the compiler generated copy constructor. If you actually want to refer to another `Auteur` consider using a `const Auteur * auteur;` member instead of `const Auteur * auteur;`. You should also consider the lifetime of the `Auteur` relative to the `Oeuvre`. Currently, the design requires that that `Auteur` outlives the `Oeuvre`. That might be fine, but make sure that this is actually true.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux , the thing is that the states of the exercice specify to define `auteur` with `const Auteur&` (pass by constant reference). And yes, actually `Auteur` outlives `Oeuvre`, because `Auteur` stands for "Author" and `Oeuvre` stands for "work" ^^ Anyway ty for your help !

Comment: @Bajyon The constructor can take the `Auteur` by `const` reference, even if the class' member is a pointer to a `const Auteur`.